# Extending CQ5 List component

Tags: aem

I'm looking into extending the cq5 list component to create custom list displays (obviously).  The constructor takes a SlingHttpServletRequest and the minimal java doc says "creates a list from the specified request".

Can someone explain how those request settings are used to build the list?  what things in the request should I change to alter the list?  Is there better documentation somewhere?

Comment: What settings are you referring too? The dialog settings?

Answer (score 2):

The component uses the request to retrieve the resource object.

In the init method it retrieves a the resource node's properties. 
The "listFrom" property should matter for you the most as it controls how the list is created. Either by querybuilder, search, retrieving the children ("children") or tags.
The List component does a simple string equals to find out which option is set and executes the associated logic.

At the end a PageIterator is returned, which is processed by the jsp.

Comment: Thomas, Thank you.  I actually decompiled the code and discovered the same thing.  I assumed that by taking the SlingHttpServletRequest it was somehow using request variables to make list adjustments, but that turned out not to be the case.

Instead, it uses the request to just grab the resource of the list node and grab properties.  Given this, I'm not sure why Day/Adobe decided to build the component/class this way, as passing 'currentNode' or something similar might have been more obvious and straightforward.

Comment: The resource centric approach is a common pattern and core concept in the underlying Sling framework. A resource is more highlevel then a Node. A node is a JCR term and is restricted by the javax.jcr API.
The Sling resource comes with some anice dditional functionality like the adapter framework.

Comment: I would highly recommend you to make yourself familar with the Apache Sling framework, CQ5 is build on top of it and makes heavy use of Sling's core concepts.

Comment: I understand all that. I just find it odd that they chose a sling request as part of the constructor when they don't use the request except to grab the resource and the resource is also available.

Comment: Yes I agree, for this reason in our project we use a baseclass to get some comfort methods and a custom tag to inject the component that does all the magic for you for exmaple injecting properties and dealing with the whole boilerplate.